# Sql injection using php

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to use SQL Injection on my local server.

My Script is:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM tbl_admin WHERE admin_name ='".$uname."' AND admin_password ='".$pwd."'";
```

Now when I'm using `admin' OR '1'='1'"; #` in name my query becomes

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_admin WHERE admin_name ='admin' OR '1'='1'"; #' AND admin_password ='*****'
```

When I check this query till 1 it is working fine. But not working in script.

I'm not getting quotes issue. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I wrote a bit of an answer on SQL injection you might want to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/18872292#18872292

Comment: Instead of `OR '1'='1'"; #`, pass `' OR 1=1;--` in the injection, it won't work if you dont close the first quote of `admin_name='`.

Comment: You might want to read up on general SQL Injection. PHP.net has some interesting material, particularly converting the type of string you use in order to try counter the Injection: http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Why do you add extra quotation mark in your input?

try with

admin' OR '1'='1'; #

Answer (score 3):

I think the information in your question is wrong:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_admin WHERE admin_name ='".$uname."' AND
```

putting in `admin' OR '1'='1'"; #` makes it:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_admin WHERE admin_name ='admin' OR '1'='1'"; #' AND
```

Which is wrong (PHP) syntax because of the final double-quote `"`.

If you put in `' OR 1=1;--`, output is compliant to the PHP syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_admin WHERE admin_name ='' OR 1=1;--' AND
```

Update:

Due to invalid edits of the original question, my answer does not fit to the rolled back revision.

Comment: Somebody botched up the bad username in an edit. The original value which the OP posted was `admin' OR '1'='1'"; #`, which would correctly inject the `OR '1'='1'` clause. Could you please edit your answer accordingly?

Comment: @Carsten I rolled the question back to the original code, thx for the hint

Answer (score -2):

use this function [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.php.net%2Fmysql_real_escape_string&ei=hscqU8PkLca8rAfTkoGQDw&usg=AFQjCNFmtI76isOytz-3XECNNBQgk3G5kA&sig2=cTTrSV_UHcYl--spczxATQ&bvm=bv.62922401,d.bmk) in your query so avoid sql injection.

Recommend to use MySqli extension for better security.

Comment: Please read questions and not blindly answer because of the familiar words you have seen in it.